# How to deploy SSRS reports to production server?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Now since I have almost completed developing a SSRS report on my local machine, I would like it to be deployed to a UAT environment.

If I specify the Target server address like this, http://[server name]/ReportServer and Deploy the report, will it work ?

What all initial setup would be required to establish a report server in Development?

After deployment, I got this error:

`The permissions granted to user 'LNM-PC\swtest' are insufficient for performing this operation.`

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

Adding your domain/local account in ssrs as an administrator may help you deploy.

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy your SSRS report on production first you need to have Admin rights of production server.

After that you need to configure Report server on production server, same time you can add permissions & roles for other users too.

With your credentials if you are able to browse report server then you can deploy it from VS with the same way - Target server addr as follows : `http://[server name]/ReportServer`.

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ask the BUILTIN\Administrators to give you the System Administrator role of the SSRS.

[image]

And also add you as Content Manager, Publisher role, etc. to the folder/report.

[image]